# Error in converting activation function from ReLU to ELU

Tags: neural-networks, python

I'm trying to convert my neural network implementation with ReLU to [ELU](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07289).

I have visualisations of the ReLU decision bounaries and they look sensible. When I convert to ELU however, the bondaries look totally wrong.

The following are the only changes I'm making:

1. `alpha = 1`
2. In forward propagation, substitute:

   ```
   A1 = np.maximum(0, Z1) # ReLU
   A1 = np.where(Z1 > 0, Z1, alpha * (np.exp(Z1)-1)) # ELU
   ```
3. In backward propagation, substitute:

   ```
   dgz = np.where(Z1 > 0, 1, 0) # ReLU
   dgz = np.where(Z1 > 0, 1, alpha * (np.exp(Z1)-1) + alpha) # ELU
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you post a pic of the boundaries. Are you sure the ELU approach converged?

Answer (score 1):

The [ICLR](https://iclr.cc/archive/www/2016.html) conference paper that you cite ([Fast and Accurate Deep Network Learning by Exponential Linear Units (ELUs), 2016, Clevert et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07289)), provides the derivative in section 3:

$$
f'(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
1             & \text{if   } x > 0   \\ 
\alpha\exp(x) & \text{if   } x \le 0. \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

It appears that your implementation (simplified)

```
  dgz = np.where(Z1 > 0, 1, alpha*np.exp(Z1))
```

is correct.

However, other factors could explain the difference with $\text{ReLU}$. For example, it could be that the $\text{ELU}$-network requires more iterations to converge. Therefore, have a look at both [learning curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve) (plotted by epoch or iteration).